# Most efficient practice to access objects in other classes: Java

Tags: java, object-reference

I am currently creating a dungeon crawler. I handle all of the dungeon generation, collision box generation, treasures and enemy generation, and player generation in one class called Dungeon. Each of the objects created in the dungeon class has a getter.

In the Main class, I am using an animation timer to handle all of the updates from the player moving, opening treasures, etc. This requires access to many of the objects created in the Dungeon class.

I am trying to better understand the use and benefit of object references in Java. My question is: What is the more efficient method to access the variables in the Dungeon class (or any other class for that matter) since I am accessing them hundreds or thousands of times?

For example, all of the treasures in the dungeon are in an ArrayList variable that is a member variable of the Dungeon class. So, I can retrieve that array list in my Main class like this: `dungeon.getTreasureList()`. If I need to get a specific item in that ArrayList I could use: `dungeon.getTreasureList().get(i)` where `i` is the index of the treasure object I want. This is fine for short calls (organizationally speaking) but it gets really messy with longer calls like so: `dungeon.getPlayer().topIntersects(dungeon.getCollisions().getWalls())`

Alternatively, I could create a reference to the treasureList in my Main like this: `ArrayList<Treasure> treasure = dungeon.getTreasureList()`. Then, if I need a specific object in the ArrayList I can call: `treasure.get(i)`. This can clean up the long call above to something more like this: `player.topIntersects(collisions.getWalls());`. This is much easier to read and, as a result, I favor this method a bit more.

Disregarding the organizational benefits, is it a better practice to create a reference to access a variable to access information, or use the longer form and getters (like this`dungeon.getTreasureList().get(i)`)?

It would seem, that by creating a reference for player and collisions in the call `dungeon.getPlayer().topIntersects(dungeon.getCollisions().getWalls())` I am saving two function calls by using `player.topIntersects(collisions.getWalls());`. Namely, one function call to `dungeon.getPlayer()`and one call to `dungeon.getCollisions()`.

Since this is being called thousands of times while the game is running, it seems safe to assume I am saving many thousand function calls to `dungeon.getPlayer()`and `dungeon.getCollisions()`, resulting in a more efficient code. Am I right in this assumption?

**EDIT: Trying to make the question more objective and less opinion based and corrected misleading phrasing**

Comment: I feel like this is a bit of a code smell; perhaps try to reorganize your logic and class responsibilities. Remember **Single responsibility principle** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: I should clarify a bit, the Dungeon class handles all of the calls to other generation classes. The dungeon map is generated in its own class, the treasures are generated in their own class, the enemies are generated in their own class, etc. I refactored a bunch of the Main in order to make sure the main was just responsible for the updating and re-rendering when changes occur in the update loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My opinion is that this question will be closed soon, because it's too opinion-based.

But if I did offer my opinion I'd say that letting classes access private collections and then operating with them is poor encapsulation.

Better to hide those details and provide methods to give the information you want without giving away the private details.

Comment: I tried to edit my question to make it less opinion based and more objective. Thanks for pointing that out. I am still learning how to best use SO.